# How can I shift my code left and right inside multiline comments in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, comments, keyboard-shortcuts, javadoc

I am writing a Javadoc and I want to shift my code left and right, but of course, it just shifts the whole line of code, not the commented content.

Is it possible to shift a comment's content with keyboard shortcuts, or is the only way to do so manually?

What I want to shift:

```java
/**
 *     content
 */
```

How it shifts with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>:

```java
/**
*     content
 */
```

How I want it to be:

```java
/**
 * content
 */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IntelliJ IDEA, this is defined by [Code Styles](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-code-style.html). In Java specifically, this is controlled by the "Continuation Indent" ("Tabs and Indents" tab) and the options on the [JavaDoc tab](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/code-style-java.html#javadoc).
So if you are looking to change indents for all JavaDoc lines, this is the option for you.

One more option is to record a macro deleting extra spaces and assigning a hotkey for it as described [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-macros-in-the-editor.html).

Comment: On the question post you commented "post a screenshot of how your code and comments are organized". That is inappropriate. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) A [mre] is appropriate. [ask] [Help] [meta] [meta.se]